# Zend Framework 2 how to get columns from multiple tables using join?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework

I am using ZfcBase\Mapper\AbstractDbMapper to write mysql queries for my project. Everything works great for single table queries. If I join with some tables the results are good but the only problem is I dont know how to select columns from "joined" tables. Here is my sample code:

```
class XYZ extends AbstractDbMapper implements XYZInterface

    {
    public function joinTables() {
         $select = $this->getSelect();
         $select->reset('columns');
         $select->columns(array('colA','colB'))
                   ->join('ABC','ABC.colA=XYZ.colA',array('colB','colC'))
                   ->where(array('XYZ.colA' => 'value1'));
         $resultSet = $this->select($select);
         $myResults= array();
         foreach ($resultSet as $myResult) {
                $myResults[] = $myResult;
         }
         return $myResults;
    }

}
```

The result $myResults is actually an array of XYZ entities. How can I have the ABC entities part of my result set $myResults?

Comment: modify the columns method appropriately

Answer (score 0):

Add `->setIntegrityCheck(false);`

I've updated your code:

```
public function joinTables() {
     $select = $this->getSelect();
     $select->setIntegrityCheck(false);
     $select->reset('columns');
     $select->columns(array('colA','colB'))
               ->join('ABC','ABC.colA=XYZ.colA',array('colB','colC'))
               ->where(array('XYZ.colA' => 'value1'));
     $resultSet = $this->select($select);
     $myResults= array();
     foreach ($resultSet as $myResult) {
            $myResults[] = $myResult;
     }
     return $myResults;
}
```

Comment: Is this applicable only in ZF 1.x? I am using the latest version and cant find this function setIntegrityCheck anywhere in vendor.

Comment: Yes you can use it in zf 1.x only, you didn't specify you weren't using zf 2

Comment: So do you know what should be the solution for ZF2?

Answer (score 0):

```
//join with columns

    $select11 = new Select;
    $select11->from('foo')->join('zac', 'm = n', array('bar', 'baz'));
   //'SELECT "foo".*, "zac"."bar" AS "bar", "zac"."baz" AS "baz" FROM "foo" INNER JOIN "zac" ON "m" = "n"';
```

Considering the above example found at [examples](https://gist.github.com/ralphschindler/3949548). Your code should look like this.

```
 $select = $this->getSelect();
 $select->from('ABC')->join('XYZ','ABC.colA=XYZ.colA' array('colA','colB'))
                   ->where('XYZ.colA = value1');
         $resultSet = $this->select($select);
         $myResults= array();
```